# Using Gson with interfaces to fetch data from API

Tags: java, json, generics, kotlin, gson

I've no experience with Kotlin and I'm trying to write an app fetching data from diffrent financial APIs using Gson. I have created two classes implementing an interface and I'd like to instantiate it in generic function. Right now I have two diffrent methods to operate on each API and I'd like to make it more decent.

EDIT:

**I want to make a generic function out of two given functions:**

Interface and two classes:

```
interface TickerEntity{

  val tickers: Array<String>

  data class MainData (
    val Bid: Double,
    val Ask: Double
  )

}

object API1TickerEntity : TickerEntity {

  val tickers = arrayOf<String>("BTC-LTC", "BTC-DOGE", "BTC-POT", "BTC-USD")

  data class MainData(
    val success: Boolean,
    val message: String,
    val result: ResultData
  )

  data class ResultData (
    val Bid: Double,
    val Ask: Double,
    val Last: Double
  )

}

object API2TickerEntity : TickerEntity {

  val tickers = arrayOf<String>("LTCBTC", "BTCDOGE", "BTCPOT", "BTCUSD")

  data class MainData(
    val max : Double,
    val min : Double,
    val last : Double,
    val bid : Double,
    val ask : Double,
    val vwap : Double,
    val average : Double,
    val volume : Double
  )

}
```

My functions to manage Json I want to be generic:

```
data class BuySell( val stockName: String, val buy: Double = 0.0, val sell: Double = 0.0)

    fun getAPI1BuySell(): () -> BuySell {
    val currency = API1TickerEntity.tickers[0]
    val response = sendRequest("somesite.com")
    val gson = Gson()
    val ticker: API1Entity.MainData = gson.fromJson(response.body, API1TickerEntity.MainData::class.java)
    println(currency)
    return { BuySell("API1", ticker.result.Ask, ticker.result.Bid) }
  }

  fun getAPI2BuySell(): () -> BuySell {
    val currency = API2TickerEntity.tickers[0]
    val response = sendRequest("someothersite.com")
    val gson = Gson()
    val ticker: API2TickerEntity.MainData = gson.fromJson(response.body, API2TickerEntity.MainData::class.java)
    return { BuySell("API2", ticker.ask, ticker.bid) }

  }
```

So far I have tried:

```
  fun <T : TickerEntity> getStockBuySell(url: String, stockName: String): () -> BuySell {

    val tickerEntity : T = T
    val currency = tickerEntity.tickers[0]
    val response = sendRequest(url.replace("{}", currency))
    val gson = Gson()
    val ticker: tickerEntity.MainData = gson.fromJson(response.body, tickerEntity.MainData::class.java)
    println(currency)
    return { BuySell (stockName, ticker.Ask, ticker.Bid) }
  }
}
```

But I can't instantiate the interface alone, and also it seems I can't override data class alone since it is not a value.

JSON files to manage:

API1:

```
 {"success":true,"message":"","result":{"Bid":0.00596655,"Ask":0.00597554,"Last":0.00597933}}
```

API2:

```
{"max":0.00606939,"min":0.0059345,"last":0.00595134,"bid":0.00594972,"ask":0.00599205,"vwap":0.00595134,"average":0.00595134,"volume":29.60407718}
```

All help appreciated

Comment: First, your question is not clear at all! please provide more information AND ask your question directly.
But as I looked to it, it seems that you want to convert the two functions into one generic. Your error must be because of that you're instantiating an interface `TickerEntity` which is not a valid action.
After all, if you provide your interface and edit your question, I think I would have an answer for it.

Comment: @MohammadOmidvar yes, sorry, I have edited the question.